# Grep and replace text with special characters

Tags: linux, replace, grep

I have 10K+ XML where about half of them have the following line of code I'd like to replace:

`<protocol_name_from_source><![CDATA[This section will be completed when reviewed by an Expert Review Panel.]]></protocol_name_from_source>`

with this:

`<protocol_name_from_source><![CDATA[Not applicable.]]></protocol_name_from_source>`

I've been able to successfully `grep` for the affected files:
`grep -rl '<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>The Expert Review Panel has not reviewed this measure yet\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>' ./`

but I can't seem to be able to replace the text with sed:

`grep -rl '<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>The Expert Review Panel has not reviewed this measure yet\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>The Expert Review Panel has not reviewed this measure yet\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>/<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>Not applicable\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>/g'`

Appreciate any help in advance.

edit: These XMLs are in a git repo. Is there any risk of corrupting the repo?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, according to my man page, sed `-i` option expect to be followed with one (eventually 0 length) extension. And the command option should be introduced with `-e` if it is not the only command parameter.

So here I would use:

`grep -rl '<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>The Expert Review Panel has not reviewed this measure yet\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>' ./ | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>The Expert Review Panel has not reviewed this measure yet\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>/<process\_review><\!\[CDATA\[<p>Not applicable\.<\/p>\]\]><\/process\_review>/g'`

Beware, I have not reviewed the (long...) sed `s/.../.../` command...